# Retrieving list of Foursquare venue items with picture

Tags: php, api, foursquare

I am developing an app that relies thoroughly on Facebook login, but I am trying to retrieve a list of local venues as well but powered by Foursquare. (userless)

They allow 5000/requests an hour which sounds reasonable at first.

If I request a list of venues I get 50 items using 1 api rate.

If I want pictures for each listing, I have to do an additional 50 loops. One for every item from the 1st response.

This is outrageous! It takes over 30 seconds to load all the data and uses 51 requests per user requesting the page.

Dramatically cuts it down to only 98 users an hour. :(

Has anyone else run into this issue before or have any workarounds?

I really, really can't resort to having two logins for one user experience and we are required to use Facebook.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried caching your results?  You can cache the venue details for 30 days (at which point you'll need to refresh your results). For someone starting up in a new area, it will definitely take a while to load, but for people in popular areas, you will hopefully not have to make all those requests, and over time will have a robust local datastore that will dramatically reduce your API calls overhead.

Comment: I'd up-vote but I don't have enough reputation yet.

I actually took this approach last night. Reduced load time from 30 to less than 3 after the first cache. Very manageable. I'm also recording how many api calls I make per city to get an idea of my usage/density. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Happy to hear that worked! I think you should be able to "accept" the answer (cause it to have a green check mark) since you asked the question, even if you can't upvote it.